# PHP count row after specific row on text file

Tags: php, count, row

I would like to count rows of text file (.txt) after specific row.

Example: I want after row 10 then row 11 until end will be count.

Is it possible?

What I've tried:

```
$files = "log.txt";
echo count(file($files));
```

But as you know it will count all rows.

What I want is, after row 10 then row 11 until end will be count.

Any idea?

**UPDATE**
Need to count only row with values, ignore for empty row/line

Comment: I'm not really familiar with PHP, but couldn't you just subtract 10?

Comment: @ricky3350 how to do that?

Comment: `echo count(file($files)) - 10;`, perhaps?

Comment: It's working, but I need to count only row with value. If empty row so do not count. Is it possible?

Comment: Please update your question to include that additional requirement @HiDayurieDave

Comment: @sheeldotme OK noted, I already update it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$files ="log.txt";
$f = fopen($files, 'rb');
$row = 1;
while (!feof($f)) {
    $row += substr_count(fread($f, 8192), "\n");
}
fclose($f);
echo $row;
```

this if empty line is not counted

```
$r  = array_filter(array_map("trim", file($files)), "strlen");
echo count($r);
```

Comment: Tried, and got different result. On log.txt have 1752 rows. On PHP script got 1764 rows

Comment: Also, ignore to count empty row

Comment: @HiDayurieDave screenshot of the rows count in your texteditor.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to markatonay but shorter:

```
$text = file_get_contents('/tmp/log.txt');
$lines = array_filter(array_map('trim', explode("\n", $text)));

print_r($lines);
echo "COUNT:" . count($lines);
echo "\r\n";
```